# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

i am getting error message: Invalid argument for foreach() in my View. I wanted to display all entries in my mysql table but i kept on getting error message. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this. The codes are the following... help me please

user_model.php

```
<?php                   
                            foreach ($daftar as $data) :
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $data->id_petugas; ?></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger remove" data-toggle="confirmation">
                                        <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                        <?php
                            endforeach;
                        ?>
```

user_controller

```
<?php
class User_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __Construct()
    {
        parent ::__construct();
    }

    function user(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['daftar'] = $this->user_model->get_user_all();

        $this->load->view('daftar_user',$data); 
    }
```

daftar_user.php

```
<?php                   
                            foreach ($daftar as $data) :
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $data->id_petugas; ?></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger remove" data-toggle="confirmation">
                                        <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                        <?php
                            endforeach;
                        ?>
```

i've a bug from this file

Comment: What does `get_user_all` look like?  (You didn't post your model, you posted your view twice.)

Comment: sorry sir, this model

Comment: function get_user_all()
  {
   $query=$this->db->query("select * from petugas order by asc");
   return $query->result();
  
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('petugas');
   $this->db->order_by('id_petugas','ASC');
   
   $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
     foreach($query->result() as $data){
      $daftar[]= $data;
     }
    return $daftar;
    } 
  
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper coding technique you were using. So please correct your model query code first like:

```
$query = $this->db->from('petugas')->order_by('id_petugas','ASC')->get()->result();
return $query;
```

No need to change anything else. You will get your all data in view.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_user_all() 
{ 
  $query=$this->db->query("select * from petugas order by asc"); 
  return $query->result(); 
  $this->db->select('*'); 
  $this->db->from('petugas'); 
  $this->db->order_by('id_petugas','ASC'); 
  $query=$this->db->get(); 
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){ 
     foreach($query->result() as $data){
      $daftar[]= $data; 
     } 
     return $daftar; 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, it worked .. thanks a lot

my login system is ok. It's working.. I have three user type 1.admin 2.customer service 3. waiter.
I need , if login into admin and cs or waiter. its redirect three different view...

I've tried divert the two different views, how should assign more than two views?

```
<?php if($level == "1"){ ?>
    <?php echo $this->view('admin/template'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
  <?php echo $this->view('cs/template'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```